# List randomly becoming empty - Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class War {

    private final List<UUID> teamOne;
    private final List<UUID> teamTwo;
    private final WarType warType;
    private final List<UUID> teamOneAlive;
    private final List<UUID> teamTwoAlive;
    @Nullable
    private final Island winnerIsland;
}
```

```
    private void tryPrepareForWar(Set<Queue> queueSet) {
        for (Queue inQueue : queueSet) {
            if (inQueue.getUuid().equals(getPlayer().getUniqueId())) continue;
            List<UUID> teamOne = getTeamMates();
            teamOne.add(getPlayer().getUniqueId());
            List<UUID> teamTwo = inQueue.getTeamMates();
            teamTwo.add(inQueue.getUuid());
            ShardWars.getPlayerQueueManagerMap().get(inQueue.getUuid()).removeFromQueue();
            removeFromQueue();
            new WarManager(new War(teamOne, teamTwo, getWarType(), teamOne, teamTwo, null)).startWar();
            break;
        }
    }
```

```
WarManager warManager = ShardWars.getPlayerWarManagerMap().get(player.getUniqueId());
        War war = warManager.getWar();
        if (war.getTeamOneAlive().isEmpty()) {
            warManager.endWar(Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamTwo().get(0)),
                    Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamOne().get(0)));
            return;
        }
        if (war.getTeamTwoAlive().isEmpty()) {
            warManager.endWar(Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamOne().get(0)),
                    Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamTwo().get(0)));
            return;
        }
```

```
if (!ShardWars.getPlayerWarManagerMap().containsKey(player.getUniqueId()))
            return;

        WarManager warManager = ShardWars.getPlayerWarManagerMap().get(player.getUniqueId());
        War war = warManager.getWar();
        war.getTeamOneAlive().remove(player.getUniqueId());
        war.getTeamTwoAlive().remove(player.getUniqueId());
        List<ItemStack> playerInventory = Lists.newArrayList();
        IntStream.range(0, event.getDrops().size()).filter(i -> event.getDrops().get(i) != null && !event.getDrops().get(i).getType().equals(Material.AIR)).forEachOrdered(i -> {
            playerInventory.add(event.getDrops().get(i));
            event.getDrops().remove(i);
        });
        ShardWars.getInventoryContentMap().put(player.getUniqueId(), playerInventory);
        if (war.getTeamOneAlive().isEmpty()) {
            warManager.endWar(Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamTwo().get(0)),
                    Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamOne().get(0)));
            return;
        }
        if (war.getTeamTwoAlive().isEmpty()) {
            warManager.endWar(Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamOne().get(0)),
                    Core.getInstance().skyblockManager.getIsland(war.getTeamTwo().get(0)));
            return;
        }
```

I'm using the Spigot API and I'm creating a player versus player type plugin. I'm using lombok for getters and constructors. `War#getTeamOne()` and `War#getTeamTwo()` randomly become empty. I print the lists throughout the code and it contains a value, but then just before I do `WarManager#endWar()`, the list is empty. Nowhere in my project do I remove from either of those lists. Any idea why that is? If you need to see more code, lmk.

Comment: Not sure what `Queue` is, but if it returns its own list of team mates, instead of a copy of it, then you're sharing it with your `War` object. Which means that if the `Queue` object empties it, it's empty in `War` as well.

Comment: ```@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Queue {

    private final UUID uuid;
    private final WarType warType;
    private final List<UUID> teamMates;
}``` 
This is Queue. And what do you mean by that?

Comment: Don't add information like that in comments. It's unreadable. Instead, [edit] the question, add the information, and add a comment to say that you have added information to the question. If the getter of the `teamMates` simply does `return teamMates`, then your `War` and your `Queue` share the same list and any changes one makes in it will be reflected in the other.

Comment: I've edited the tryPrepareForWar method, would that work?